# Does altitude variance effects geofencing?

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, geofencing

I need to implement a auto-check in feature for managing office attendance.Will accuracy of geofencing be effected if office is situated on 50th floor.ie Does altitude variance effects accuracy of geofencing?

Comment: i don't think so..

Comment: @NarendraPandey So while registering a region does its altitude be also registered?

Comment: Yes you think as a Region. But actual process is that it store Longitude and latitude of particular region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accuracy is not an issue (geofencing is based on lat/long coordinates, which are the same regardless of the floor). The issue is going to be GPS accuracy. Due to the fact that GPS is not able to penetrate walls, the GPS coordinates will nearly always show you outside of the building, not inside of it. Not to mention being able to identify which office room someone has entered.

If this is acceptable accuracy level for your project, then just GPS works. If you need to see that the person has actually entered the building or the specific office, you will need to utilize beacons.

(Disclosure: I work for Proximi.io, a technology-agnostic positioning platform)